# Pass and receive parameter into Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I develop my plugin based on Eclipse. I want to define and pass parameter into Eclipse and my plugin can receive

For example

```
/soft/eclipse-3.7.2/eclipse -data /user/nquan/workspace -var1 value1 -var2 value2
```

In my Eclipse plugin, how can I get value of var1 and var2?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform` to get the application arguments:

```
String [] args = Platform.getApplicationArgs();
```

Comment: it not work. 
- Step 1: Run Eclipse: eclipse-3.7.2/eclipse -var1 value1 -var2 value2 
- Step 2: Create a class and get value

    String[] args2 = Platform.getApplicationArgs();
    System.out.println(args2.length);
    for (String string : args2) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

Result: 0

Comment: When you run an application the arguments are specified in the 'Run > Eclipse application' configuration. You can only access the Eclipse command line arguments when you install your plugin in to Eclipse.